# how to get tool tip text displayed in selenium

Tags: selenium

am trying to check the tool tip text displayed in web page. there will be a question mark symbol on which if we mouse over there will be a text displayed . I want to get that text

i **tried**,

```
element = web.findElement(By.xpath(name));

element.click();
String text = element.getAttribute("title");
```

but text is not displayed.

Comment: You'll need to provide a HTML snippet that shows us this particular element. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Please find the example code.

```
String tooltip=wd.findElement(By.xpath(locator of the element)).getAttribute("title");
System.out.println(tooltip);
```

Hope this will ne helpful.

Comment: i tried even using ACTION but it is not working am getting Exception in main thread